# delete home directories in ActiveDirectory using VB

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap, ado, adsi

I want to use VB to search the AD for disabled accounts (older than 90 days and delete their home directory. The following script works fine but **not recursively** :(

Can anyone help to make this working? Any help would he highly appreciated :)

```
Option Explicit

Dim objOU, objUser, objFSO, strHomeDirectory, objTextFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://OU=users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com")

objOU.Filter = Array("user")

For Each objUser In objOU
if ( objuser.useraccountcontrol = 514 Or objuser.useraccountcontrol = 66050 ) And DateDiff("d", objUser.WhenChanged, Now) > 90 Then 
    ' Retrieve home directory.
    strHomeDirectory = objUser.homeDirectory
    ' Replace %username% with value of sAMAccountName attribute.
     strHomeDirectory = Replace(strHomeDirectory, "%username%", objUser.sAMAccountName)
    ' Delete the folder.
     objFSO.DeleteFolder strHomeDirectory
else
wscript.sleep 100
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally do that with an [LDAP query](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx). If you'll forgive the shameless plug, I wrote a [class for AD queries](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/adquery.shtml) a while ago to simplify this kind of task. You could copy/paste the code to your script and use it like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set qry = New ADQuery
qry.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person)" & _
             "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
qry.Attributes = Array("sAMAccountName", "homeDirectory", "whenChanged")

Set rs = qry.Execute

If Not rs Is Nothing Then
  Do Until rs.EOF
    If DateDiff("d", rs.Fields("whenChanged").Value, Now) > 90 Then
      homedir = rs.Fields("homeDirectory").Value
      homedir = Replace(homedir, "%username%", rs.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value)
      If fso.FolderExists(homedir) Then fso.DeleteFolder homedir
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
  rs.Close
End If
```